# How to use variable in instantiateViewController in Swift IOS

Tags: swift

```
let screen = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: self.screenPresenter.screenPresenterIdentifier) as? variable_name
```

I have to use some variable_name in `as?` and

```
variable_name = type(of: object_name)
```

and

```
object_name = ExampleViewController()  // ExampleViewController is of type UIViewController
```

Edit:-
means i want to ask after as? we have to provide some Class in which we have to convert like let screen = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: self.screenPresenter.screenPresenterIdentifier) as? ExampleViewController here ExampleViewController is hardcoded so I want to make it dynamic and take input from user in which class user wants to convert?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You question is not clear to answer, rewrite or edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's get some terms right. When you add `as?` followed by a `Type` after a variable, it means you are *Type Casting* (casting for short) the variable into the `Type`. Basically you are telling the compiler that you want to handle the object as the type you are casting to. Casting only works if the object is actually the type or the type family you are casting to. You can not cast to unrelated types. There are two forms of casting. The `as?` form is the *conditional form* while the `as!` is the *forced form*. Because casting can failed, therefore the `as?` will return the results wrapped in optionals while the `as!` will crash your app when fail to cast.

There is no way to cast an assignment to a type defined in runtime (dynamic as you have put it) for Swift. The type needs to be defined at compile time. However, there are ways to use type erasure to not care about the exact type during assignment.

1. Cast as AnyObject. By casting as AnyObject, you're wrapping the object with the type AnyObject (similar to optionals). However when you want to use the object within, you'll need to cast the AnyObject type back to the actual type of the object to use it. Unless the code you are writing is for storage or transporting of these objects, it is not very useful otherwise.
2. Cast as parent class. Cast to parent class type of all possible class you'll be assigning to the variable. The downside is that the object you are trying to use must be in a class hierarchy and the cast need to use the parent to all that may be assigned. For example. Class A is the parents of Class B and Class C. Class B is the parents of Class D. If you case using Class A, the assignment of A, B, C, or D, will succeed but if you cast as Class C, Class D will fail to be cast as Class C. Therefore, it's only useful to you if the objects you will ever need to cast is the child or grand child of the class you are casting to.
3. Cast as Protocol. This is similar to #2 except all the object you try to cast must implement the protocol. You can always use extension to add protocol to any class in Swift but you will need to do that before you can cast that class to a particular protocol.

For further information, please read Apple's documentation on [Type Casting here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html).